# Achieving dynamic Android LinearLayout height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout

I am currently designing the widget for my app (see attached screenshot). Using a LinearLayout I was able to create the following setup:

1. Image: weight - 2
2. Title section: weight - 1
3. Price section: weight -1

However I would like the title and price section to be of fixed height while the image's height changes (shrink or grow) when the user resizes the widget.

How can I make the height of the image dynamic without using layout_weight? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a resizable image section all I had to do was change the weight of the Image to 1 and set the actual height in dp for the title and price section.

**UPDATE**

A more efficient alternative is to use RealtiveLayout, this can be achieved by:
1. Having the price section having fixed height and aligned to parent bottom
2. Set the title section having fixed size and above the price 
3. Set the image as match_parent height and above the title.